# Did Trump say "I" or "I'd" "probably have a very good relationship with Kim Jong-un."?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, applied-linguistics

The Wall Street Journal (WSJ) says Donald Trump stated in an interview:

> I probably have a very good relationship with Kim Jong-un.

Trump denies this, claiming that he said:

> I'd probably have a very good relationship with Kim Jong-un.

Let's call the first sentence A and the second one B.

The WSJ then [released a recording](http://www.wsj.com/video/disputed-audio-from-donald-trump-interview-with-wsj/33003B4D-0DA4-4760-B913-0C2CDC903E74.html) claiming to corroborate that Trump said A.

Surprisingly, the White House then [released a recording](https://twitter.com/PressSec/status/952405070955544576) claiming to corroborate that Trump said B.

Perhaps this is a case where the tools and expertise of phonetics (such as spectrographic analysis) could be convincing. Do the recordings provide any evidence that Trump said (or attempted to say) "I'd" here, i.e. that he said (or attempted to say) B and not A?

Comment: It's impossible to tell without palatographic evidence. The "I probably have" interpretation makes absolutely no sense, if that's relevant.

Comment: @user6726 re: "The "I probably have" interpretation makes absolutely no sense, if that's relevant.", I'd have to disagree with you there. Sentence A is perfectly grammatical to me.

Comment: Grammaticality is not the issue, it's the pragmatic implication of one versus the other. "I probably have bought that brand" is a plausible believe, and it is reasonable to think that someone would say such a thing. Anyhow, it's unclear what you mean by "say".

Comment: Sentence A is apt to say if you have limited knowledge of your relationship with someone (as in the case of Trump-Kim, where interaction is via remote communications and the reactions of the other cannot be gauged as well as in face to face communication.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Linguistics.

Comment: @bytebuster: Really? It seems to me like the kind of thing Mark Liberman might post about on Language Log. Colin, if your question is closed here, I think you should consider sending Liberman an email. He's made blog posts in the past about linguistic features of interest in things presidents have said, he's interested in the topic of [accurate quotations in journalism](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4119), and he is an expert in the area of phonetics/phonology so he should be able to say something intelligent about possible phonetic analysis.

Comment: (E.g. this seems similar to the "[bigly](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=24240)" thing)

Comment: @sumelic In fact, Liberman just posted about it http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=36251#more-36251

Comment: @Colin: ah, yep! In light of that, would you even want reopen votes on this Q? I do think this question is on-topic, but I doubt you'll get answers here that are more informative than Liberman's post. Let me know if you want me to vote to reopen.

Comment: @As a user of this site, I'm disappointed that the question was closed, since it seems to fit under the categories "Linguistics phenomena [sic] during history " or "a single word in relation to multiple languages or a single word/single language ". However, I would agree the discussion on LL is likely to be more fruitful.

Comment: In general, I feel like linguistics.se is particularly trigger-happy about downvoting and closing as off-topic questions whose topics happen to be exactly the ones that I'd see discussed in an academic linguistics class, such as this one.

Comment: I have to agree with user6726 - it seems a bit of a stretch to say you're in a good relationship with someone after threatening to tear apart each others' countries...

Comment: 'It seems to me like the kind of thing Mark Liberman might post about on Language Log.' - Funnily enough, that's the first thing that came to mind when I saw the same question on Reddit earlier...

Comment: Unfortunately, the fact that this question was closed shows - very clearly - the current state of affairs on LE. From a vibrant platform for insightful discussion of matters that make linguists’ hearts beat faster it has turned into a lackluster website full of put-on-hold/voted-down questions.

Comment: I guess I'll vote to reopen and we'll see if that will end up happening. I hope so. I don't know if you've seen this related ELU question; there's some analysis in the answers there: [Is D-glottalization a plausible explanation of ambiguity in Donald Trump interview with WSJ?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/426473)

Comment: @AlexB., For voting to close questions, it's pretty much the usual suspects. It's irritating.  I wonder if they are ever embarassed about closing good questions.

Answer (score 1):

No, the conflicting claims about what was said are not necessarily a phonetic issue.  We ordinarily refer to what was intended or perceived to be said when quoting or otherwise characterizing what someone said.  For instance, if you say "Ib probably" that might well be interpreted, and quoted as "I'd probably", because in American English, a t/d/n before a word starting with p/b/m often becomes a labial, pronounced with the two lips, in partial agreement with the following labial p/b/m.

This and perhaps further phonetic changes could make "I'd probably", as measured by instruments, sound like "I probably".

Comment: Fair point, but it seems to me that what was intended to be said, what was perceived to be said, and what was said are 3 different things, which may or may not be defined for a given utterance. In the scenario you describe, "I'd probably" is what was perceived, and "Ib probably" is what was said. I'm asking what was said by Trump (as what was perceived to be said is clear, and what was intended is less determinable).

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify that I am asking whether the recordings provide positive evidence for the presence of "'d" at all. (That he said "I...probably have a very good relationship with Kim Jong-un. " is not in dispute)

Comment: I don't see how you clarified the question at all. Are you asking about his articulation? His intention to articulate? The acoustics of what was conveyed in the online recordings? The acoustics of what came out of his mouth? What words he had in mind to use? What are our choices (you present a false dichotomy, which makes sense *only* if you are not asking about his actual speech but are using his speech as potential evidence about his word-intent). In other words, that do you even mean by "what was said"?

Comment: @user6726 what I added was " Do the recordings provide any evidence that Trump said "I'd" here, i.e. that he said B and not A?". That is, is there any acoustic evidence present in the recordings that "'d" was said?

Comment: I agree that phonetics may not help us much here. cf. Saur's comment "Trump's idiosyncratic pseudo-humble "probably" [...] is certainly IRR, but **he has a notably shaky grasp on how Anglophones typically express themselves subjunctively. He frequently omits modals and auxiliaries** and enjoys inhabiting a kind of beatific flowing present from which he may pluck ideas about the future and experiences from the past without the bother of a grammatical change to mark the departure of time and tense" [emphasis mine - A.B.].